# count NAs for every participant long format

Tags: r, count

I've got a data frame in a long format, with 90 rows for each participant. Now I want to exclude every participant that has more than 10 NAs in some specific columns. So for example if the have more than 10 NAs in the column called rating1 or more than 10 NAs in rating 2.

I thought that I have to solve this with a for loop. But I don't know how. So I want to go it through the first 90 rows and check if there are more than 10 NAs, then through the next 90 rows and so on and save the ids of these cases somewhere so I can exclude them. 
Is it clear what I try to achieve?

I tried this and got at least the sum for the first 90

```
colSums(is.na(dato[1:90,]))
```

Comment: Could you clarify that you want to exclude based on one specific column or 10 `NA`s within any one of many columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarification, here is an approach with `dplyr`:

Note that `everything()` does not include the `group_by` columns.

```
data %>%
  group_by(Participant) %>% 
  filter(all(colSums(across(everything(), is.na)) <= 10))
```

Here is some sample data:

```
set.seed(3)
data <- data.frame(Participant = rep(1:10, each = 90), setNames(as.data.frame(replicate(20, sample(c(NA,1:13),size = 900, replace = TRUE))),paste0("rating",1:20)))

data %>% group_by(Participant) %>% summarize(S = list(colSums(across(everything(),is.na)))) %>% unnest_wider("S")
# A tibble: 10 x 21
   Participant rating1 rating2 rating3 rating4 rating5 rating6 rating7 rating8 rating9 rating10 rating11 rating12 rating13 rating14 rating15
         <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1           1       5       4       5       6       8       6       3       7       7        5        4        5        4       10        6
 2           2       5      13      12       4       8       4       6       7      10       10        9        8        7        3        7
 3           3       5       7       8       6      10       6       4       7       6        9        7       10        6       12        6
 4           4      10       7       7       3       3       8       6       5       5        5        6        3        5       11       14
 5           5       5       7       4       5       9       4       5       3       4        7        5        4        6        3        5
 6           6       4       3       2       4       5       4       4       5       6        6        7        7        5        8        6
 7           7      11       7       6       5      11      11       4      10       6        7        7        7        5        4        9
 8           8      11       6      11       5       4       5      12       5       5        5        8        1       12        8        4
 9           9       3       5       3       8       6       8       5       8       4        6        8        6        6        5        8
10          10       4       3       9       6       7       6       5       6      10        7        6        7        9        5        6
# … with 5 more variables: rating16 <dbl>, rating17 <dbl>, rating18 <dbl>, rating19 <dbl>, rating20 <dbl>
```

Comment: I tried this and wanted to save the data without these cases in datnew. So I put datnew in front of your code like this datnew <- data %>%... However I get the opposite result: There are the data of the cases that have more than 10 NAs and the one with less is deleted

Comment: See my edit to filter *out* across 20 result columns on any with more than 10 `NA`s.

Comment: Thanks so much! Can I ask you another question to see if I got the logic right? If I have got another exclusion criterion that says that every participant with a mean RT > 2000 should be exluded, can I write : `data <- data %>%
  group_by(participant) %>% 
  filter(mean(RT) <= 2000)`

Comment: That should work. Sounds like you've figured it out. Although you might need `mean(RT, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `is.na.data.frame` :

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1:3, NA),
                 col2 = c("this", NA,"is", "text"), 
                 col3 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), 
                 col4 = c(2.5, 4.2, 3.2, NA))

is.na.data.frame(df)

      col1  col2  col3  col4
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

rowSums(is.na.data.frame(df))

[1] 0 1 0 2
```

Comment: But this only counts the NAs in the column for the whole data frame, right? Not separated by participants

Comment: 0 is for 1st row(participant), 1 second, 0 third, 2 fourth, etc... so I wouls say it's by participant. Not so verbose as dplyr, but does the job

Comment: Ok thanks for your clarification. I think I prefer the dplyr solution. But anyway I really appreciate your idea as well. Thanks so much